# Android Lint flagging NewAPI Error where it should not

Tags: java, android, lint

In my Android project I have `minSdkVersion` set to `19` and `targetSdkVersion` `26` in the manifest file. In one of the Java files I schedule an alarm using two different API's using an if statement for checking the current version of Android:

```
private void scheduleAlarm(AlarmManager alarmManager, long targetTime, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent) {
    if(VersionCheckUtils.isLollipopOrLater()) { // Lollipop is version 21
        // Code for versions after Lollipop
        logAlarm(targetTime, pendingIntent, intent, "Lollipop");
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(targetTime, pendingIntent),
                pendingIntent);
    }
    else {
        // Code for older versions
        logAlarm(targetTime, pendingIntent, intent, "Kitkat");
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Now Lint does not analyze the `if` statements and reports this error:

```
NewApi: Calling new methods on older versions
../../src/main/java/org/bee/beezone/trafficcontrol/AlarmScheduler.java:61: Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.app.AlarmManager#setAlarmClock
```

How can you deal with this situation? The code should actually be safe, but Android lint does not seem to understand this.

In the end I have deactivated "NewApi" checks by adding these lines to the gradle build file:

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        disable 'NewApi'
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you get the error because you are mixing in a single method two different methods for different api version.

You can:

- Use @SuppressLint("NewApi") annotation on your scheduleAlarm method

or

move out the code inside the if conditions and use the @TargetApi(n) annotation

```
private void scheduleAlarm(AlarmManager alarmManager, long targetTime, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // Lollipop is version 21
        // Code for versions after Lollipop
        alarmLaterLollipop();
    }
    else {
        // Code for older versions
        alarmBeforeLollipop();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void alarmLaterLollipop(){
    logAlarm(targetTime, pendingIntent, intent, "Lollipop");
    alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(targetTime, pendingIntent),pendingIntent);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void alarmBeforeLollipop(){
    logAlarm(targetTime, pendingIntent, intent, "Kitkat");
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution than what I have suggested in the question.